# Is this how to create a bullet point array in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand the best way to input each item in an array as an li element

I'm confused because it seems like there is a better way, or that may implementation isn't right despite it working when I run the code.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

        inputValue: '',
        inputValue2: '',
        todo: [], 
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
  }

  mapList() {
    return this.state.todo.map(x => <li>{x}</li>);
  }

  handleAddToDo = () => {
    this.setState({
      todo: [...this.state.todo, this.state.inputValue ]
    })
    console.log(this.state.todo);
    this.setState({inputValue: ''})
    this.mapList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <input type="text"
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={(e)=> this.handleInputChange(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={()=> this.handleAddToDo()}>
          Add to To-Do list
        </button>
        <ol>
          {this.mapList()}
        </ol>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly doing it right. Here is my try. I just removed some unnecessary parts and made all functions arrow ones.

You don't have to invoke your functions in your JSX props like onChange or onClick, just use the function reference. Actually, use it always like this. So, your functions are not created in every render.

You don't need to invoke this.mapList() in handleAddTodo, since after your state changes, your component will re-render and mapList will run again.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
      inputValue: '',
      todo: [],
      id: 0,
    }

  handleInputChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })


  toggleCompleted = ( e ) => {
    // We are caching event values since SyntheticEvent
    // cannot be used asynchronously.
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    const id = e.target.id;

    // We are mapping todos, finding related one with id
    // then change its completed status to our checked value.
    this.setState( prevState => ( {
      todo: prevState.todo.map(
        el => {
          if ( el.id === Number( id )) {
            return { ...el, completed: checked}
          }
          return el;
        }
        )
    }))
  }

  mapList = () =>
    this.state.todo.map(x => (
      <Fragment key={x.id}>
        <li>{x.value}</li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={x.completed} id={x.id} onChange={this.toggleCompleted}/>
      </Fragment>
    ))

completedList = () => this.state.todo
    .filter( el => el.completed )
    .map( el => (
      <Fragment key={el.id}>
        <li>{el.value}</li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={el.completed} id={el.id} onChange={this.toggleCompleted} />
      </Fragment>
    ))

  // We change our todo shape here. Array of objects and it holds
  // value, and mimic an id. 
  handleAddToDo = () =>
    this.setState( prevState => (
      { todo: [...prevState.todo, { value: prevState.inputValue, completed: false, id: prevState.id + 1 }], inputValue: "", id: prevState.id + 1 }
    ))

  render() {
    console.log( this.state.todo );
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <input type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddToDo}>Add to To-Do list</button>
        <ol>
          {this.mapList()}
        </ol>
        <p>Completed Todos</p>
        <ul>
          {this.completedList()}
        </ul>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply! One more thing I don't understand at all how to do, and I've done a lot of searching. What if I wanted to add a checkbox inside the <li> on each item that if checked would move the specific element in the array to a new array that's for finished todo items? I'm getting confused about the JSX and Javascript mixed with HTML. I know Javascript decently and HTML very well, but mixed is confusing :)

Comment: Probably you want to hold the todo data not just an array but object of arrays and some property like `completed`. Then, somehow bind your checkbox to your todo, then change the completed prop. I don't know how to tell bind part since I'm not so good at html, forms and inputs :) By the way, I've edited my answer for some minor issue. You should not setState multiple times in the same place, you can do all state changes in one time (handleAddTodo).

Comment: Phew, not so elegant but it works :) I've edited my answer and added checkboxes. Just mimicking creating todo with ids and values and changing its state.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand much better now. Although in your code, I don't understand what this is doing: 

    handleAddToDo = () =>
    this.setState( prevState => (
      { todo: [...prevState.todo, { value: prevState.inputValue, completed: false, id: prevState.id + 1 }], inputValue: "", id: prevState.id + 1 }
    ))

Comment: So, I also don't get now how I would return an array of completed items. Something like this?

`completedList = () =>
     this.state.todo.filter(x => (
     this.state.todo.id.completed === true)
     ))`

Comment: For the first question I think you don't get the callback function in setState. setState is an async operation and when we do state changes based on the same state itself there could be some race conditions. So, we are using a callback for this. See more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate For the filter part, here is x your todo element and you will check x.completed not x.id.completed. We have todos like `{value: "foo", id: 1, completed:true}`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to filter and render properly. But, this question is getting longer :) I suggest you follow some free or paid React tutorials and code along with them. This is how you learn properly and see some best practices. By the way, if my answer is ok for your question you can accept it. So, one question will be dropped from the list which has not an accepted answer and I will get some reputation :)